# How close is the median of a uniformly chosen subsample to the median of the full set?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, sampling, median

Take $N$ a set of n numbers, sample s numbers from $N$ uniformly and with replacement giving us the set $S$.

What is the relationship between the median of $N$ and the median of $S$ ?

I want a result that looks like:

With probability ... the median of $S$ has a rank in $N$ in
$\left[\left(\frac12 - d\right)n, \left(\frac12 + d\right) n\right]$.

I am actually interested in a proof of Lemma 13 of https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3409964.3461790 (which comes without a proof)

Thanks :)

Comment: @AaronMontgomery: Sets don't contain copies.

Comment: @joriki Ah, of course! Silly mistake on my part. Although, now I'm not entirely sure what to do with the fact that the drawing is to take place with replacement and still construct a set from it....

Comment: @AaronMontgomery: The elements of the set don't matter – the question only asks about the rank of the median.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery: $d$ only appears in an expression for the rank of the median, and the median itself is also determined solely by rank. You can relabel the elements in $N$ any way you want – as long as you're only interested in things determined by ranks, all that matters is their linear order.

Comment: @joriki Yes, of course. I see now. Thank you!

Comment: Yes sorry, the set S is actually not a set but a multi-set, it could contain multiple times the same element.